# Magento Query issue - add OR condition

Tags: magento

```
$collection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter(array('attribute'=> 'name','like' => '%test1%'));    
$collection = $collection->addAttributeToFilterPOS(array('attribute'=> 'name','like' => '%test%'));
```

Is there any other way to add OR condition between 2 addAttributeToFilter function Magento?

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name',array('like' => array('%test1%','%test2%')));
```

hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

To use addAttributeToFilter() with an OR condition you can pass an array of arrays like this:

```
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
array(
    array(
        'attribute' => 'name_of_attribute_1',
        'null' => 'this_value_doesnt_matter'
    ),
    array(
        'attribute' => 'name_of_attribute_2',
        'in' => array(115, 116)
    )
)
);
```